# trying to send image from esp32cam to raspberry pi3, not recieve but got a confirmation signal, espressif framework

Tags: c, pyqt5, esp32

Hi im trying to send images taken from my esp32cam i manage to stablish the conecction but for some reason the image is not recieve, but also im waiting for a response from the server, and i do get a response but its only hex letters and i have no idea why its send that way, i atach my code below, and honestlly im lost on this one

it suposes the image is been recieve beacause im sending a signal from the server, but its not been show on the server side and the response is of the type, ***dC,?dC,?U,?*** honestly i have no idea whys that, i should recieve on the client side ESP_OK

im using the esp32cam with platformio + espressif framework on the client side, and python/pyqt5 on the server side

any idea what it might be?

**esp32cam**

```
void stream(camera_fb_t *fb_camera){

    esp_http_client_config_t config = {
        .url = "http://192.168.1.208:7500",
        .transport_type = HTTP_TRANSPORT_OVER_TCP,
        .method = HTTP_METHOD_POST,
        .event_handler = stream_handler,  // pendiente
        .keep_alive_enable = true,
    };
    // Log("before init");
    
    //  size_t mem =esp_get_free_heap_size();
    // char mem_free[50];
    // sprintf(mem_free,"Aviable memory: %u", mem);
    // Log(mem_free);
    esp_http_client_handle_t cliente = esp_http_client_init(&config);    // error here!!!!!!
    if (cliente == NULL){
        Log("bad handle check"); 
    } else {
        Log("Good handle");
        // esp_err_t error_open = esp_http_client_open(cliente, fb_camera->len );
        // vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //wait 100ms
        // if (error_open == ESP_FAIL){ Log("Cannot open conecction");}
        // int error_write = esp_http_client_write(cliente, (char *)fb_camera->buf, fb_camera->len);
        // vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //wait 100ms
        // if (error_write <= 1){ Log("Cannot write frame buffer");}
        // if (esp_http_client_fetch_headers(cliente) < 0){ 
        //     Log(" Something went wrong on the headers"); 
        // } else {
        //     int resp = esp_http_client_get_status_code(cliente);
        //     char resp_code[50];
        //     sprintf(resp_code, "Response from server: %i", resp);
        //     Log(resp_code);
        // }
        // vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //wait 100ms
        // if (esp_http_client_close(cliente) == ESP_OK){Log("Conecction closed");}


        esp_err_t error_method = esp_http_client_set_method(cliente, HTTP_METHOD_POST);
        if (error_method == ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG){Log("Bad method argument");}
        esp_err_t error = esp_http_client_set_post_field(cliente, (char *)fb_camera->buf, fb_camera->len);
        if (error != ESP_OK){Log("post failed");}
        esp_err_t http_error = esp_http_client_perform(cliente);    
        vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS); //wait 100ms

        if (http_error == ESP_FAIL){
            const char* err = esp_err_to_name(http_error);
            int err2 = esp_http_client_get_status_code(cliente);
            char stream_error[100];
            sprintf(stream_error,"Http error: %s, %d", err, err2);
            Log("Error couldnt write fram");
            Log(stream_error);
        } 
        
        // int content = esp_http_client_get_content_length(cliente);
        // char *buffer = (char *)malloc(content +1);
        // int read = esp_http_client_read(cliente, buffer, content);
        // //buffer[read] ='/O';
        // Log(buffer);
        // free(buffer);
        while(http_error != ESP_FAIL){
            vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            char * buffer = malloc(MAX_HTTP_RECV_BUFFER+1);
            int content = esp_http_client_fetch_headers(cliente);
            int read_size = esp_http_client_read(cliente, buffer,content);
            buffer[read_size]='\O';
            
            Log(buffer);
            free(buffer);
            // if (buffer == "ESP_OK"){
            //     free(buffer);
            //     break;
            // }
            // sprintf(resp_code, "Response from server: %i", resp);
            // Log(resp_code);
        }
        
    //if (esp_http_client_cleanup(cliente) == ESP_OK) {Log("Cleaning done");} else {Log("Error while cleaning");}
    }
}
```

**raspberry pi server, where the images are been shown**

```
def run(self):
    self.log("starting socket")
    buffer = b''
    tunnel = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.log("after socket")
    # host = socket.gethostname()
    # ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
    
    # self.log("sup")
    # self.log("socket ip {0} and hostname {1}".format(ip, host))
    
    wi_ip = nt.ifaddresses('wlan0')[nt.AF_INET][0]['addr']
    self.log("socket ip {0}".format(wi_ip))
    tunnel.bind((wi_ip, self.port))
    tunnel.listen(3)
    
    clntunnel, addrs = tunnel.accept() 
    self.log("conected to ip: {0} on port: {1}".format( addrs[0],addrs[1] ) )
    while True:
        try:
            data = clntunnel.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                self.log("no data")
                break
            #self.log("data recieve")
            buffer = buffer + data
            if not buffer:
                self.log("No data on buffer")
            # else:
            #     self.log("new data")
            while True:
                frame, buffer = self.extract_jpeg(buffer)
                #self.log("Checking")
                if frame is None:
                    #self.log("no data on frame")
                    break
                clntunnel.send.encode("ESP_OK")
                self.new_frm.emit(frame)
        except:
            self.log("Someting went wrong, no conecction")
    tunnel.close()
```